# How to generate key pair in a Spring Authorization Server clustered environment

Tags: spring-authorization-server

Considering I have a few instances of a Spring Authorization Server clustered behind a load balancer, how do I generate a key pair so that all instances work correctly?

Is there a recommended way to share key pair between instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the `JWKSource` interface (from the Nimbus library) and store the keys in a data store that is accessible by all nodes in the cluster. Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-enterprise-authorization-server/blob/main/authorization-server/src/main/java/com/example/authorizationserver/RsaKeyPairRepositoryJWKSource.java) and [presentation](https://youtu.be/ELz8wNt_Rys?si=pejMkgXiDDiTx84Q) which demonstrates an implementation.